# Combine regex with different groups of criteria

Tags: .net, regex

I wanted to write a regex that would validate this: info-444444-test.json where 444444 could be any number 0-9 and 6 characters

My current regex is (info-)|(^[0-9]{6}$)|(-test.json) but it does not work on website such as https://regex101.com/

At the end I need to implement the regex into .NET into method It.IsRegex from Moq library.

Comment: You need `^info-[0-9]{6}-test\.json$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qPiJCw/1).

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern `(info-)|(^[0-9]{6}$)|(-test.json)` there are 3 alternatives where the pattern is trying to match each alternative starting from the left giving you partial matches.

You can use a pattern to match all the parts as one match.

This is

```
^info-[0-9]{6}-test\.json$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `info-` Match literally
- `[0-9]{6}` Match 6 digits 0-9
- `-test\.json` Match `-test.json` (Note to escape the dot)
- `$` End of string

See a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5einfo-%5b0-9%5d%7b6%7d-test%5c.json%24&i=info-444444-test.json)